# Mighty Mouse clones?

Tags: hardware-recommendation

Does anybody make a (preferably BT/wireless) Mighty Mouse knockoff? It's my favourite mouse design by a long margin, but Apple doesn't make them any more and the old ones all have bad scroll balls by now :-/

Comment: You could have mine for the price of the postage - though that's probably well outside SE rules ;-) I threw it in a drawer within a couple of weeks of getting it, back in 08 - couldn't get used to the weird right-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Mighty Mouse, is still available, it's often used by Schools, Colleges and Universities where they want to tie the mouse down from being pinched.

Apple now called it the Apple Mouse.

You can find it here: http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB112ZM/C/apple-mouse

Comment: Sweet! I might buy a palette :)